# `tf.function` decorator causes batch shape to be `NoneType` (Tensorflow2, Python)

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.x

In the following code:

```py
@tf.function
def get_x_y(dataset,count=1):
  X = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32,count)
  Y = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32,count)
  idx = tf.Variable(0,dtype=tf.int32)
  for batch in dataset.take(count):
    max_x,max_y,max_z = batch.shape
    x = tf.slice(batch,[0,0,0],[-1,max_y-1,-1])
    y = tf.slice(batch,[0,1,0],[-1,-1,-1 ]) 
    y = tf.argmax(y,-1)
    y = tf.cast(y,tf.float32)
    X = X.write(idx.numpy(),x)
    Y = Y.write(idx.numpy(),y)
    idx.assign_add(1)
  return X.stack(),Y.stack()
```

Output when using wihtout `tf.function` decorator is as expected, however with the `tf.function` decorator, the following error occurs:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-2306b6173e70> in <module>()
----> 1 print(get_x_y(dataset))nt 

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-55-4a32428fa07d>:8 get_x_y  *
        x = tf.slice(batch,[0,0,0],[-1,max_y-1,-1])

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Expected output is a 2-tuple of(tensorA,tensorB) of shapes `(count,batch_size,batch_seq_len,vocab_size)` and `(count,batch_size,batch_seq_len)` respectively, with

```js
count = argument provided to the function
batch_size = 128
batch_seq_len = ?, max_len(seq_i) for all seq in batch
vocab_size = 78
```

For example, an expected output when the function is not decorated with `tf.function`:

```py
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 128, 262, 78), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        ...,

        [[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 128, 262), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 7., 53., 69., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [15., 21.,  5., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [15., 77.,  5., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        ...,
        [15., 77.,  5., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [15., 77.,  5., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [15., 77.,  5., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)>)
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why? I suspect it is because the dataset is of the shape `<MapDataset shapes: (128, None, 78), types: tf.float32>`, however I do not understand why `max_y` is `None` because the batch shape is known before looping?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you well:
You have a problem with `max_y` as none and it is as part of size parameter to `tf.slice` throw an exception.

strided_slice() requires 4 arguments input_, begin, end, strides.

The functionality of the method is quite simple:
It works like iterating over a loop, where begin is the location of the element in the tensor from where the loop initiates and end is where it stops.

So please try:
Here steps or strides can be `dataset.take(count)`

```
tf.strided_slice(input, [start1, start2, ..., startN],
    [end1, end2, ..., endN], [step1, step2, ..., stepN])


max_y = tf.Variable(np.array(batch) 
s = tf.strided_slice(max_y, begin, end, max_y, name='var_slice')
```

Comment: Hi Mahsa, thank you for your answer. You have understood correctly that the issue is , with `max_y` being `None`. However, `max_y` is not supposed to be the batch, only the length of the second axis of the batch. In addition I do not want to get a numpy array from batch, that would force computation off the GPU. The issue is that when I attempt to do `_,max_y,_ = batch.shape`, `max_y` ends up being `None` if the `tf.function` decorator is used to disable eager execution.